# Why jpa can't see just added data

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jpa

After adding data to the database, I try will address to these to data.
But JPA can't see just added data. If I redeploy, JPA can see that data.
In what the reason and how to fix it?

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="client")
@NamedQuery(name="Client.getAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c")
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public  Long id;

@Column(name="first_name", length = 25)
private String firstName;

@Column(name="surname", length = 25)
private String surName;

@Column(name="password", length = 30)
private String password;
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
```

**ClientDAO**

```
public EntityManager em =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Vlad").createEntityManager();

public void add(Client client){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(client);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}
    public List<Client> findClientByEmail(String email){
    return em.createQuery(
            "SELECT  c FROM Client  c WHERE c.email LIKE :custEmail")
            .setParameter("custEmail", email)
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getResultList();
}
```

**ClientService**

```
    public Client login(ClientDTO clientDTO){
    List<Client> clientList;
    clientList = clientDAO.findClientByEmail(clientDTO.getEmail());
    validLogin(clientList);
    Client client = clientList.get(0);
    validLogin(clientDTO, client);
    return client;
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
    <persistence-unit name="Vlad" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clients"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**UPD 1**

```
**ClientService**
    public void register(ClientDTO clientDTO){
    validData(clientDTO);
    uniqueEmail(clientDTO);
    Client client=new Client();
    client.setFirstName(clientDTO.getFirstName());
    client.setSurName(clientDTO.getSurName());
    client.setPassword(clientDTO.getPassword());
    client.setEmail(clientDTO.getEmail());
    client.setNickname(clientDTO.getNickname());
    clientDAO.add(client);
```

Comment: Where is the data being added and read? Do you do that in one transaction or 2 separate ones? Assuming you're using `add(Client)` somewhere, do you start the "read" transaction before calling that method?

Comment: try using jpa repository in spring boot project. Its very simple to use, you will only need to add mysql-connector dependency to your pom to get things working seamlessly.

Comment: You could try to close the transaction and open a new one for your find method. No need to redeploy.

Comment: I`m not shure, but try to `em.flush()`

Comment: @AshutoshJha it's my first project and i want write this project using jsp+jpa

Comment: @Thomas Adding and reading data you can see in my UPD 1 method register(it's add), findClientByEmail(that place where i try read added client in database).. I use only one transaction when i add data